# Minecraft split-screen on Android TV possible without console?

Tags: android-tv

I've read that Minecraft pocket edition is playable on Android TV through sideloading.

I've also read that the only edition of Minecraft which supports split screen is the console edition.

Regardless, my question is if there is some way to play split screen Minecraft on Android TV (with game controller support), without first getting a console?

My TV is running Android Lollipop and will soon receive Marshmallow.

Comment: Unless you can port Nougat to It, change the MCPE app so it has two versions of itself installed at once, then *somehow isolate files, sound and input* I highly doubt so.

Comment: @Dan Brown Thanks, I suppose it also isn't possible to cast split screen from two other Android devices, or to find an emulator which can run the console version on the TV?

Comment: No, It's not I'm afraid. Even if you could get two running, there'd be conflicts everywhere.

Comment: @Dan Brown I think you are right. I have yet to find an xbox 360 or PS3 emulator for Android, or an app which enables split-screen casting from two android devices. (Although I don't see how there would be conflicts. An emulator would run Minecraft console edition which has built-in support for split-screen. And in the other case, when casting from two devices, my idea was that the devices would handle sound and input and only the screens would be streamed to the TV). Thanks again for the help. I've decided to buy a console.

Comment: Kiradge No problem. The conflicts would have been controls btw